# Tensorflow Transforming a 2 dimensional list of words to indices of their characters

Tags: tensorflow

I have a 2 dimensional tensor of strings that looks like this:

```
array([[b'This', b'is', b'a', b'word', b'here'],
       [b'hello', b'world', b'how', b'are', b'you']], 
       dtype=object)
```

I want to turn it into a 3 dimensional tensor of indices using a lookup table which maps characters to indexes (let's call this lookup table 'chars_lookup') The result would have for each word its characters mapped into indices.

Suppose my lookup_table has the following mapping:

```
{T:1, 
 h:2, 
 i:3, 
 s:4,
 a:5,
...}
```

Then the output would look something like:

```
array([ [[1,2,3,4], [3,4], [5], [6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,11]],
        [[10,11,13,13,7], [14,7,12,13,14], [...], [...],[...]],
      ], 
       dtype=int64)
```

I have tried all sort of variations with map_fn but couldn't find how to do it.
Any example of a code that does something similar would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the mappingin the lookup table to make the question more clear?

Comment: The main problem is that the output that you want is not a tensor, because the last dimension has a variable size. Do you want to obtain a [ragged tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor)? Or some other output format (e.g. tensor + mask or something else)? The second problem is that your lookup table is a dict, which is not a TensorFlow structure... Are you using only ASCII characters? Are all characters in the words guaranteed to be found in the lookup table? What version of TensorFlow are you using? Can you please give a full example, with input, full lookup table and output?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are okay with getting a ragged tensor, and that your lookup table is given as a Python dictionary, this is a simple way to do that:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def chars_to_nums(a, lookup_table):
    lookup_map = tf.constant([lookup_table.get(bytes([i]), -1) for i in range(256)])
    a_bytes = tf.strings.bytes_split(a)
    idx = tf.ragged.map_flat_values(lambda x: tf.io.decode_raw(x, tf.uint8), a_bytes)
    return tf.gather(lookup_map, tf.dtypes.cast(idx, tf.int32))

a = tf.constant([[b'This', b'is', b'a', b'word', b'here'],
                 [b'hello', b'world', b'how', b'are', b'you']])
lookup_table = {b'T': 1, b'h': 2, b'i': 3, b's': 4, b'a': 5, b'w': 6, b'o': 7,
                b'r': 8, b'd': 9, b'e': 10, b'l': 11, b'y': 12, b'u': 13}
tf.print(chars_to_nums(a, lookup_table).to_list())
# [[[[1], [2], [3], [4]],
#   [[3], [4]],
#   [[5]],
#   [[6], [7], [8], [9]],
#   [[2], [10], [8], [10]]],
#  [[[2], [10], [11], [11], [7]],
#   [[6], [7], [8], [11], [9]],
#   [[2], [7], [6]],
#   [[5], [8], [10]],
#   [[12], [7], [13]]]]
```

---

EDIT: If you want to do the replacements using Unicode "characters" (codepoints, I will assume), you can do the following:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def chars_to_nums(a, lookup_table):
    # Get sorted list of mappings
    keys, vals = zip(*sorted(lookup_table.items()))
    # Get key codepoints
    keys_cp = tf.constant(list(map(ord, keys)), dtype=tf.int32)
    vals = tf.constant(vals, dtype=tf.int32)
    # Convert strings to codepoints
    a_cp = tf.strings.unicode_decode(a, 'utf8')
    # Find the index of the replacement
    idx = tf.ragged.map_flat_values(lambda x: tf.searchsorted(keys_cp, x), a_cp)
    # Replace with mapped values
    return tf.gather(vals, tf.dtypes.cast(idx, tf.int32))

a = tf.constant([[b'This', b'is', b'a', b'word', b'here'],
                 [b'hello', b'world', b'how', b'are', b'you']])
# Lookup table contains unicode codepoints
lookup_table = {'T': 1, 'h': 2, 'i': 3, 's': 4, 'a': 5, 'w': 6, 'o': 7,
                'r': 8, 'd': 9, 'e': 10, 'l': 11, 'y': 12, 'u': 13}
tf.print(chars_to_nums(a, lookup_table).to_list())
# Same output as before
```

Comment: Thanks - my input is Unicode strings - so I think your suggested approach will not work for me as it will require a lookup_map for all Unicode values.

Comment: @Gaddy I added a different version that would work for Unicode codepoint replacement.

Comment: Thanks @jdehesa - that does the trick. I needed to have the result as a tensor - so I also called to_tensor() on the final result.